# Finding Eigenvalues And Eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra

When looking for Eigenvalues (and Eigenvectors) could we use the row operation adding/subtracting rows to create a new matrix, with the same determinant to find the Eigenvalues?

Comment: Gaussian elimination does not preserve eigenvalues. And that's quite expected, because otherwise finding the roots of a generic polynomial just by adding and multiplying its coefficients would not only be possible, but extremely easy.

Comment: Sure you can, provided you apply this process to the matrix $A-\lambda I$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust but the eigenvalues are not preserved

Comment: @gbox: why not ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Of course, if we think about $A-\lambda I$ we can use row (or column) operations, but I wonder for what kind of matrices such operation would have practical meaning leading to the simplification of calculations ?

Comment: @Widawensen: how do you evaluate determinants efficiently ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I rarely do it by hand (most often case $2 \times 2$), I apply computer for this - how computers are performing the task?, maybe they use Laplace expansion as I do when I  need determinant for jacobian?

Comment: @Widawensen: Laplace is catastrophic for larger determinants (say starting from $4\times4$), never use it ! Use Gaussian elimination. Even for expansion of the polynomial.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you for the advice, fortunately  for larger dimensions we have also computers, although sometimes symbolic calculations require some method..

Comment: @Widawensen: I am commenting about manual computation.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I see Yves. Some examples would shed a light on the problem... such comparison of efficiency of different methods .. but how to measure efficiency?.. perhaps with the number of needed operations..

Comment: @Widawensen: the computational complexities are well-known to be $O(n!)$ and $O(n^3)$, with similar hidden constants.

Comment: @YvesDaoust So the situation is clear..

Answer (score 1):

Try row addition
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix} \rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix} $to see that characteristic polynomial for these cases can give different eigenvalues.

However as you see transition from matrix 1 to 2 doesn't change eigenvalues, but not transition from 2 to 3.
So it would be interesting a question in what situations eigenvalues are unchanged by a row operation ...